# Is there a way to create a Workflow Rule to send administrator an email only when a new opportunity is created by a Partner Community?

Tags: lightning-experience, workflow, automation

In our Org, we allow Partner Community members to create and own Opportunities. As the administrator, I would like to receive an email alert only when Partner Community members create an Opportunity, not when In-House users create an Opportunity.

The reason for this is that I need to ensure that the new Opportunities are being assigned to the appropriate person.

I have created an email alert and assigned it to a workflow rule, but the email is being sent even when the Opportunity is created in-house.

Comment: use criteria where $Profile.Name = 'thePartnerCommunityProfileName`

Comment: @cropedy, Thank you.  Your answer worked for me...but in reverse.  Because our business model has more profiles which may have reason to create opportunities than thoes who should not, i set the criteria to exclude only "House" profiles.  Now I only receive the alert  when some creates an opportunity who does 'not' have a profile equal to "House".  Outstanding!

Comment: you might want to accept the answer as a service to the Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow rules (and for that matter, Process Builders, Lightning Flows, Visualforce Pages, Formulas, and Validation Rules) have access to certain runtime variables about the current user:

```
$User.xxx     // properties of the current user like $User.Email
$Profile.xxx  // properties of the current user's profile like $Profile.Name
$UserRole.xxx // properties of the current user's role like $UserRole.Name
$MyCustomPermission // presence of a custom permission held by current user
$Setup.XXX.field__c // value of hierarchical setting XXX's field__c
```

The available values of xxx can be found in the UI's formula editor.  For Workflows, Salesforce also surfaces the $User, $Profile, and $UserRole in the `Current User: xxx` dropdown in the rule editor.

So, in your example, the WFR criteria would be:

```
$Profile.Name <> 'House'
```

or

```
 Current User: Profile not equal House
```